# Dynamically reformatting an excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very messy excel sheet that I'm trying to reformat into something readable. Currently, it is structured as such (each large separation resembles a new cell):

```
Title1    Var1   Var1_Value    Var1.1    Var1.1_Value ... Var1.K Var1.K_Value
Title2    Var2   Var2_Value   Var2.1    Var2.1_Value ... Var2.L  Var2.L_Value
...
TitleM    VarM   VarM_Value   VarM.1    VarM.1_Value ... VarM.N  VarM.N_Value
```

To clarify, the amount of variables and values per column varies for each row, however every variable will have a value. Ultimately, my end goal is to create something formatted as such:

```
Title1    Var1    Var1_Value
Title1    Var1.1  Var1.1_Value
...
TitleM    VarM.N  VarM.N_Value
```

Where the Title string is repeated for each Var and Var_Value in its row.

I don't know a lot about VBA, so I'm looking for help on the best avenue to achieve this formatting. Here is my thought process in psuedocode below, I tried to format to be VBA-esque when I could.

```
for idx = 1 To lastRow
      ' Will likely have to create a function to find 
      ' last filled column in a row -- lastColForRow
      tempArray = data(idx,2 To lastColforRow(idx))
      for jdx = 1 To length(tempArray)-1 Step 2
          newCell(end+1,1) = data(idx,1)
          newCell(end+1,2) = tempArray(j)
          newCell(end+1,3) = tempArray(j+1)
      next  jdx
next idx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do it (note that it assumes that there is no header row)

```
Public Sub Reformat()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim numrows As Long
Dim i As Long, ii As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1

            lastcol = .Cells(i, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            'integer division so as to get the number of value pairs
            numrows = lastcol \ 2
            'only do anything if we have more than one value pair
            If numrows > 1 Then

                'insert extra rows for extra value pairs
                .Rows(i + 1).Resize(numrows - 1).Insert
                'copy the titles down to all new rows
                .Cells(i, "A").Copy .Cells(i, "A").Resize(numrows)
                'a value pair at a time, cut and copy to next new row
                For ii = 4 To lastcol Step 2

                    'target row is current row (i) + the value pair index ((ii /2)-1)
                    .Cells(i, ii).Resize(, 2).Cut .Cells(i + (ii / 2) - 1, "B")
                Next ii
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Bob! At first glance it looks like it does the job -- I'm going to dig around in this a little bit more to understand what is going on.

Comment: I've added a few comments to help you along with that understanding

Answer (score 1):

This does it with arrays onto a new sheet

```
Sub climatefreak()
Dim lastrow&
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastcolumn&
Dim idx&
Dim ClmIdx&
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim i&
Dim trw&


Set tws = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For idx = 1 To lastrow
        Dim temparr
        lastcolumn = .Cells(idx, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        temparr = Range(.Cells(idx, 1), .Cells(idx, lastcolumn)).Value
        For i = LBound(temparr, 2) + 1 To UBound(temparr, 2) Step 2
            trw = tws.Range("A" & tws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            tws.Cells(trw, 1) = temparr(UBound(temparr, 1), 1)
            tws.Cells(trw, 2).Resize(, 2) = Array(temparr(1, i), temparr(1, i + 1))
        Next i
    Next idx
End With



End Sub
```